# How to use Kaleidoscope 2 with Git Tower?

Tags: git, git-tower

Kaleidoscope 2 public beta was released this week and has gained merge functionality. Yay! However, the command-line usage is somewhat vague about the usage. I want to use Kaleidoscope together with Git Tower, how can I do that?

```
$ ksdiff --help
usage: ksdiff - send files to Kaleidoscope
command options:                        
  [--wait, -w | --no-wait]              whether to wait for the document to be
                                        closed in Kaleidoscope before exiting

FILE options:
  [--snapshot | --no-snapshot]          whether the file is temporary. this
                                        option will override the heuristics
                                        ksdiff would otherwise use to determine
                                        this state.

commands:
  --merge                               send a merge
                                        implies --wait
    --output OUTPUT                     use OUTPUT as the destination path for
                                        this merge. creates OUTPUT if it does
                                        not exist.
    [--base BASE]                       use BASE as the base content for this
                                        merge. can improve the quality of the
                                        default selections for some merges.
    FILE FILE                           the files to merge
```

[Support docs for external merge tools from Git Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/files/applicationHelp/pgs/Integration_DiffTools.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update as of Git Tower 1.4.14**

Git Tower (version 1.4.14 and above) now ships with Kaleidoscope 2 integration. The launcher scripts shown below should not be used anymore, as they do not work correctly with Kaleidoscope 2 final version.

---

Kaleidoscope provides the correct command line usage when Integration > Git merge is chosen. The correct launcher script for Git Tower looks like this:

**~/Library/Application Support/Tower/CompareScripts/kaleidoscope2.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

LOCAL="$1"
REMOTE="$2"
BASE="$3"
MERGED="$4"

APPLICATION_PATH=/Applications/Kaleidoscope.app
CMD="$APPLICATION_PATH/Contents/MacOS/ksdiff"

"$CMD" --merge --output "$MERGED" --base "$BASE" -- "$LOCAL" --snapshot "$REMOTE" --snapshot
```

**~/Library/Application Support/Tower/CompareTools.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>ApplicationIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.blackpixel.kaleidoscope</string>
        <key>ApplicationName</key>
        <string>Kaleidoscope</string>
        <key>DisplayName</key>
        <string>Kaleidoscope</string>
        <key>LaunchScript</key>
        <string>kaleidoscope2.sh</string>
        <key>Identifier</key>
        <string>kaleidoscope2</string>
        <key>SupportsMergeTool</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks, Bouke!!! These scripts will be part of our next official Tower release. If you want to have these before the next update, you can also download them here: http://bit.ly/SMAMyU

Comment: This didn't work for me... but then I realised that in Kaleidoscope, there is an "Integration" menu option, and the first item installs the Command-Line Tool that Tower needed.

Comment: @MikeGledhill please read the 'update'; Kaleidoscope 2 support is integrated in Git Tower.

Comment: refer : https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/integration/custom-diff-tools

Answer (score 13):

If you're using the MAS version of Kaleidoscope, you must install the ksdiff tool manually in order for Tower to be able to launch Kaleidoscope.

Download it here http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/ksdiff2

Answer (score 13):

The missing link for me was going to: http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/ksdiff2 and installing the Kaleidosope command line tools (ksdiff), currently my "Read More" button in "Kaleidoscope > integrations.." is not linked so I hope that helps somebody else who may have been unsuccessful. Another possible missing step is the Tower Command Line Utility installation in "Tower > Preferences > Integration", from there you can go to "Git Config" tab and select Kaleidoscope as your Diff/Merge Tool.

Answer (score 4):

Our latest release (version 1.4.14) of Tower now officially supports Kaleidoscope 2 as a MergeTool. You can now download it from the [Tower Website](http://www.git-tower.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you **added** the .sh and the changes to the .plist, you **must remove** them if you upgrade Tower to 1.4.14 or above, or else Kaleidoscope won't launch. I had added the changes manually, and I have Tower version 1.4.15, and Kaleidoscope did not want to launch until I removed the changes.

I also have the MAS version of Kaleidoscope 2.0 and installed the ksdiff tool.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed when updating to Git Tower 1.4.14. I've updated my answer to reflect this.